# Constant crop aspect ratio using PEPhotoCropEditor library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crop, aspect-ratio

I'm using [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor) library in one of my iOS project. I able to having constant aspect ratio (1:1) with following code.

```
- (void)openEditor {

    PECropViewController *controller = [[PECropViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.image = self.imageView.image;

    UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;   
    CGFloat width = image.size.width;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height;
    CGFloat length = MIN(width, height);

    CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
    controller.imageCropRect = CGRectMake((width - length) / 2,
                                          (height - length) / 2,
                                          length,
                                          length);


//     Restricted to a square aspect ratio
    controller.keepingCropAspectRatio = YES;
    controller.cropAspectRatio = 1.0;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But then I needed to have aspect ratio (height:width) of (1:3) instead of (1:1).

```
controller.cropAspectRatio = 1.0f / 3.0f;
```

I tried above and nothing happened. Still having same aspect ratio. Then I change below code too.

```
controller.imageCropRect = CGRectMake((width - length) / 2,
                                      (height - length) / 2,
                                      length * 3,
                                      length);
```

Again nothing happened. After commenting above I hard coded the value like below.

```
controller.imageCropRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 100.0f);
```

Then the cropping area displayed correctly but when resizing that aria will lead to destroy the crop aspect ratio (1:3)

Any idea how to remain aspect ratio (1:3) till all editing process complete?

Comment: Did you get answer? I am having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in ViewdidAppear in PECropViewController.m

```
 self.cropAspectRatio = 1.0f;

 self.keepingCropAspectRatio = YES;
```

And pass value to function setKeepingAspectRatio in PECropRectView.m

```
- (void)setKeepingAspectRatio:(BOOL)keepingAspectRatio
{
   _keepingAspectRatio = keepingAspectRatio;

  if (self.keepingAspectRatio) {
     CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
     CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
     self.fixedAspectRatio = your_fixed_aspect_ratio_value;//fminf(width / height, height / width);
   }
}
```

you will get expected result.